# "Absolutely" and "definitely" in AE and BE

Tags: american-english

Is "absolutely" as used colloquially in "You're absolutely wrong/right!" or "Absolutely!" more typical to AE than BE?

Parallelwise, is "definitely" the preferred term in BE to express such agreements?

Comment: They occur with roughly equal frequency in Australia (which is an instance of BE).

Comment: For what it's worth, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absolutely+true%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cabsolutely+true%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cdefinitely+true%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cdefinitely+true%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsolutely%20true%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsolutely%20true%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdefinitely%20true%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdefinitely%20true%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows virtually no difference between AE and BE for "absolutely true" and "definitely true".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be much of a guide, but *absolutely* occurs twice as often as *definitely* in the spoken sections of both the British National Corpus and the Corpus of Contemporary American English.

Comment: Just an opinion, really, but I have the feeling Americans in general are more likely to stretch the "usage limits" for "degree adverbs" qualifiers like *absolutely, definitely, totally*. I can't say exactly what's "iffy" about forms such as *X is totally not Y*, but it definitely sounds more like something a (younger?) American might say. On the other hand, [Absolutely Fabulous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_Fabulous) sounds thoroughly British to me, and I don't *think* that's purely because of the TV show and the actual word "fabulous".

Comment: @BarrieEngland I'm afraid it indeed is not much of a guide, as long as what is referred to in the OP is "Absolutely/definitely" as colloquial interjections of agreement. As a nonnative speaker, I would tend to think "absolutely" is to a certain extent more BE than AE usage because it's a stronger overstatement than "definitely", and as such sounds more typical to AE than BE colloquial speech, but I may be quite wrong on that one. ;)